# Should IFRAME or IMG be used to insert google map in website

Tags: html, google-maps

To insert a map into my website, I have been using server-side code to create something like the following.  I thought I had a good reason for originally doing it this way, but now do not recall the reason. Doing a quick search shows that most solutions use an IFRAME.  Is the IFRAME solution the best approach, or are there reasons why my IMG solution is sometimes better?  Thanks

```
<img alt="Map" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=5th+%26+College+St%3Ch1%3EHello%3C%2Fh1%3E+SEATTLE+WA+98101&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=400x400&amp;sensor=false">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using IMG, which uses the [Google Maps Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), creates a static image that your users can only see, [for example as seen in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8PdpS/):

[image]

That uses the following code:

```
<img alt="Map" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=5th+%26+College+St%3Ch1%3EHello%3C%2Fh1%3E+SEATTLE+WA+98101&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=400x400&amp;sensor=false">    ​
```

However, when you create an IFrame, that allows the users to *interact* with the map, for example pan, zoom out, choose between "Map, Sat, Ter, and Earth modes", as seen in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ue7D/1/):

[image]

The code that produced that:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=53.800651,-4.064941&amp;spn=11.629588,33.815918&amp;t=m&amp;z=6&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

So too recap, IMG produces a STATIC image, while IFrame produces a dynamic interaction (Panning, zooming etc.)

NOTE: Google limits you if you go the IMG way to

> 25 000 free static map requests per application per day.

which should be enough for most but it is useful to know. If you need more, look into Google Maps API for Business.

Comment: Thanks CC Inc.  Nice descriptive answer!  For viewing only, would you recommend just a static IMG?  Does Google limit one more than the other?

Comment: @user1032531 Sure! Yes, for viewing only, IMG is the best because there is NO chance the user will mess with it. I don't think you can do static in IFrame. Now, as for your second question, it seems that if you don't use Maps for Business, you have `25 000 free static map requests per application per day.`